# Android query sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite

What am I doing wrong!?!?? 
I am trying to get a set of data to a listview.

First I Open the database and then I trying to get the set, 
I get a response but only 1 row from the database and I am getting at least 10 when I trying it in sqlite browser.....
Anyway I don't know if this make any sense, here is the code: (i am new at this, please don't laugh to much)

And btw I use the same methods/functions in another listview but then I don't have any WHERE in my query and that works fine.... 
So I want to get all the rows from the database and i only get the first one :)

Thanks mates!

```
db.openDataBase();
Cursor c = db.getCoursesFromCountyID(countyID);
BindsimpleCursorAdapter(c);
db.close();

the getCoursesFromCountyID = 
int id = Integer.parseInt(county);
        return db.query("Courses", new String[]{KEY_course_ID, KEY_course}, KEY_county_ID + " = " + id, null, null, null, null);

And the BindsimpleCursorAdapter looks like this = 

startManagingCursor(c);
        SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.simpleadapter_courses, c, new String[]{DataBaseHelper.KEY_course_ID, DataBaseHelper.KEY_course}, new int[]{R.id.courseID, R.id.course});
        ListView lv = new ListView(this);
        lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listViewCourses);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any problems on your code, try adding 'KEY_county_ID' to you projection argument and removing the selection argument to check if all the rows are really there.

Comment: So i have tried with no where, and i got all the data... so I tried to write the colum name instead of having it as a key. And it WORKS!!! The only thing I edit was:
THIS
return db.query("Courses", new String[]{KEY_course_ID, KEY_course}, KEY_county_ID + " = " + id, null, null, null, null);

TO THIS
 return db.query("Courses", new String[]{KEY_course_ID, KEY_course}, "countyID  = " + id, null, null, null, null);

Thanks man!!!! AWESOME!